# PHP Regex: Can I put an end of string $ in a range?

Tags: php, regex

Can I put the end of string character in a range like this:

```
$string=preg_replace('/([a-z])([ \,$])/','$2',$string);
```

So it matches any lowercase letter, then either a space, comma or end of string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alternation:

```
([ ,]|$)
```

If you use `$` inside a character class then it only matches a literal dollar sign.